# Antd searchable Dropdown with checkbox

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, antd

I am using antd NPM package to create a searchable dropdown like the below,
[image]

Using Menu as below,

```
<Menu.Item key="btc">BTC1
   <Checkbox style={{ float: "right" }} />
</Menu.Item>
```

I am trying to add a search filter in the dropdown but cannot figure out the solution.

Highly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using `dropdownRender` with antd Select component,

```
<Select
    optionLabelProp="label"
    bordered={false}
    value={selectedItems}
    mode="multiple"
    defaultValue={defaultValue}
    searchValue=""
    onChange={handleChange}
    dropdownRender={() => {
      return <>{menu}</>
    }}
    maxLength={2}
    maxTagCount={2}
    showArrow
    showSearch={false}
    className="filtertered-dropdown-select"/>
```

The menu,

```
  const menu = (
    <Menu className="ant-dropdown-menu" style={{ alignContent: 'center' }}>
      <Menu.Item>
        <Input
          placeholder="Input search text"
          prefix={<SearchOutlined />}
          value={clearSearch}
          autoFocus
          onChange={e => {
            setFilteredItems(
              dropdownValues.filter(original => original.value.toLowerCase().startsWith(e.target.value.toLowerCase()))
            )
          }}
        />
      </Menu.Item>
      _.chain(filteredItems)
            .groupBy('category')
            .map((value, key) => {
              if (key && key !== 'undefined') {
                return (
                  <Menu.ItemGroup key={key.toLowerCase()} title={key}>
                    {menuItems(value)}
                  </Menu.ItemGroup>
                )
              }
              return menuItems(value)
            })
            .value()
    </Menu>
  )
```

MunuItems,

```
const menuItems = items =>
  items.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <Menu.Item
        key={item.value}
        onClick={e => {
          if (selectedItems.includes(item.label)) {
            const newArray = selectedItems.filter(val => val !== item.label)
            setSelectedItems(newArray)
          } else {
            const newArray = [...selectedItems, item.label]
            setSelectedItems(newArray)
          }
        }}
      >
      {item.label}
      <Checkbox style={{ float: 'right' }} checked={selectedItems.includes(item.label)} />
    </Menu.Item>
  )
})
```

Hope it helps someone.